# Removing duplicate IP's from a list with no concern of variables after them

Tags: regex, csv

I have this kind of list (csv):

```
100.100.100.1,"10","2019-02-12 16:20:23"
100.100.100.1,"10","2019-02-12 16:20:28"
100.100.100.2,"10","2019-02-12 16:20:26"
100.100.100.2,"10","2019-02-12 16:20:27"
```

So I Would like to know the best solution with RegExp to remove duplicate IP's  from a list (by removing whole line). Values after IP should have no importance. First occurrence of IP might as well be the one that stays.

So the output should be:

```
100.100.100.1,"10","2019-02-12 16:20:23"
100.100.100.2,"10","2019-02-12 16:20:26"
```

I am using Notepad++

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

You can search with the following regex with the ". matches newline" option checked:

```
^(([^,]+).*?)^\2,[^\n]*(\n|$)
```

and replace the matches with:

```
$1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/j91kjJ/1

Comment: This only works if the appearances are consecutive, not if they are mixed up. I don't see any possibility to remove duplicates that are not consecutive in Notepad++.